# Updating state from child component to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling with an issue of App.js which has a Checkboxes component. When someone ticks a checkbox in that component, I want the state for that checkbox to be updated in the App.js file. The code for my Checkboxes component is below. I am using material ui if that makes any difference.

```
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

export default function CheckboxLabels() {
  return (
    <FormGroup row>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox name="checkedD" />}
        label="Remove Duplicates"
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

The code in App.js that is relevant is:

```
<Grid>
  <Checkboxes  />
</Grid>
```

What should I be doing? How do I modify the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the state in the `App` component, then you need to pass a function to your child component which will be used to send the state to the parent (`App`) component.

In your parent component, you would create the state so that each state of checkboxes can be stored and pass the function that will handle the updating of the state. I would store the state in `Map` to avoid having duplications of the same checkbox on each update. Also, pass an `id` to each of the Checkbox components so that you know which state refers to which checkbox when updating later on.

```js
import React from "react";
import CheckboxLabels from "./CheckboxLabel";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkboxes: new Map()
  };

  handleClick = (e, id) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      checkboxes: prevState.checkboxes.set(id, checked)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CheckboxLabels id={1} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        <CheckboxLabels id={2} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        <CheckboxLabels id={3} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        <CheckboxLabels id={4} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In your child component, you would accept the function and the `id` and then pass that function with the `event` and `id` in `onChange` method of the checkbox.

```js
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";

export default function CheckboxLabels({ id, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <FormGroup row>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox name="checkedD" />}
        label="Remove Duplicates"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, id)}
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

This way, you can store the state of multiple checkboxes and you can easily track which state is which by an `id`.

Comment: I don' understand hooks - I am using a class component. Also, having seen the code sample provided, it might be relevant that in my actual app, I will have about 10 different checkboxes, each of which I want to track the state. Will that make a difference?

I am quite new to React and programming again. I've spent hours on this one thing and getting nowhere. :(

Comment: Can you share your code through codesandbox and paste the link here? It will be easier to help you by looking at the exact code you have. I will then be able to show you and explain how to do it using class components and also how to store the state of each checkbox

Comment: @Jon I've updated my initial answer with using class components and storing the state of multiple checkboxes. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am a bit new to stackoverflow and very new to codesandbox! Here is the link so you can see what I am working on and the reasons why I need that checkbox thing working: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-dust-tcle7?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Jon I've edited your code and added a function that handles all of the checkboxes and saves them to the corresponding state. What you can do now is call the relevant functions to update the text in the switch statement that I wrote or using the state booleans of these checkboxes write the logic in componentDidUpdate(). https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-sky-zmd3n?file=/src/components/App.js

Comment: Hey thanks Mantas. Appreciated. Some of the coding is currently beyond me but I can use that as an example and learn from it. I like how you have made the checkboxes scalable using the Switch statement. Oh, and I was born in Stoney Stanton, which I believe is in your neck of the woods.

Comment: No worries, @Jon. If you need any further help, I'm here. That's great, it's a lovely place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular state mechanism in parent and just pass it down to `CheckboxLabels` component. So send `setChecked` and `checked` values down:

```js
export default function CheckboxLabels({ checked, onChange }) {
  return (
    <FormGroup row>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Checkbox
            name="checkedD"
            checked={checked}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (onChange) {
                onChange(e.target.checked);
              }
            }}
          />
        }
        label="Remove Duplicates"
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Grid>
      <CheckboxLabels checked={checked} onChange={setChecked} />
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

I am not sure if your code is good naming-wise, but I added that checkbox component is name `CheckboxLabels`